# RPn handle negative number division

Tags: c, calculator, postfix-notation

Currently, I am making a calculator inputing mathematical expression and use RPn to calculate it. Therefore, I use a infix to postfix converter function to convert it. The calculator works by pushing number into stack and detecting operator. But there is a flaw in my calculator, it cannot handle negative number division such as 1/-1. Did I understand RPn wrong or my infix to postfix function has problem?

Detecting numbers and operators

```
int isOperator(char e){
    if(e == '+' || e == '-' || e == '*' || e == '/' || e == '^')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int isNumber(char c) {
    if ((c>='0' && c<='9') || c=='.') {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Converting mathematical expression to postfix

```
void pushPostfix(struct postfixStack* s,int item){
    if(s->top == (100-1)){
        printf("\nSTACK FULL");
    }
    else{
        ++s->top;
        s->data[s->top]=item;
    }
}

char popPostfix(struct postfixStack* s){
    char a=(char)-1;
    if(!isEmpty(s)){
        a= s->data[s->top];
        --s->top;
    }
    return a;
}

void infixToPostfix(char* infix, char * postfix) {
    char *i, *p;
    struct postfixStack stack;
    char n1;
    emptyStack(&stack);
    i = &infix[0];
    p = &postfix[0];

    while (*i) {
        while (*i == ' ' || *i == '\t') {
            i++;
        }
        if (isNumber(*i)) {
            while (isNumber(*i)) {
                *p = *i;
                p++;
                i++;
            }
            *p = ' ';
            p++;
        }
        if (*i == '(') {
            pushPostfix(&stack, *i);
            i++;
        }
        if (*i == ')') {
            n1 = popPostfix(&stack);
            while (n1 != '(') {
                *p = n1;
                p++;
                *p = ' ';
                p++;
                n1 = popPostfix(&stack);
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (isOperator(*i)) {
            if (isEmpty(&stack)) {
                pushPostfix(&stack, *i);
            }
            else {
                n1 = popPostfix(&stack);
                while (priority(n1) >= priority(*i)) {
                    *p = n1;
                    p++;
                    *p = ' ';
                    p++;

                    n1 = popPostfix(&stack);
                }
                pushPostfix(&stack, n1);
                pushPostfix(&stack, *i);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    while (!isEmpty(&stack)) {
        n1 = popPostfix(&stack);
        *p = n1;
        p++;
        *p = ' ';
        p++;
    }
    *p = '\0';
}
```

Comment: This code is very hard to read.

Comment: There are two ways to handle the negation operator. Either treat it as part of the number, or store it on the RPn stack as a different character, for example `#`.

Comment: I just added a few functions I was using inside `infixToPostfix` to makes it more clear.

Comment: Don't forget that you can return conditions. :)

Comment: @user3386109 when I treated it as a number by adding the condition `(c>='-9' && c <='-1')` into `isNumber` the 1/-1 division result is -1 but the 10/-10 is also -10. Since I am evaluate the the operator by using condition like this `if (t[0] == '+') { c = a + b; }`. How can I add the condition `#` as you suggest?

Comment: When the input contains a `-` at the beginning of an expression, or immediately following another operator, change the character to `#`. Get the following number and push it onto the RPn stack, then push the `#`. When the code reads a `#` from the RPn expression, it should pop the number, negate it, and push it back onto the stack.

Comment: Perhaps if `-` is followed by digit, it is negation , else subtraction.

Comment: These are distinct operators, like they are on a regular calculator (+/- button vs - button).  The unary minus takes one operand and inverts it.  The binary minus takes two operands and subtracts them.  Do whatever you need to do to distinguish them, could be as simple as a space.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider something like this.

```
   #define PLUS +
   #define MINUS - 
   #define UMINUS _
   #define DILIM_CLOSE 1
   #define DILIM_OPEN 0
   #define OPERAND 2
   #define FACT !

   // i is the present location being parsed in the infix string
   // infix is an array holding the infix string
   // this code can go to the tokeniser
   // optr_type returns the type of operator, or even if it is an operand

   if(infix[i]==PLUS || infix[i]==MINUS)
     {
         int sign=1,st=i;

         while(infix[i]==PLUS || infix[i]==MINUS)
             if(infix[i++]==MINUS)
                 sign*=-1;

         if(sign==-1)
         {

             if((optr_type(infix[st-1])==OPERAND) ||optr_type(infix[st-1])==DILIM_CLOSE || infix[st-1]==FACT)
                 return MINUS;

             else
                 return UMINUS;
         }

         if(sign==1)
         {
             if((optr_type(infix[st-1])==OPERAND) || optr_type(infix[st-1])==DILIM_CLOSE || infix[st-1]==FACT)
                 return PLUS;
             else
                 return UPLUS;
         }
     }
```

When you detect that there have been a streak of minuses after a plus or minus, keep on flipping the sign. If `sign = -1`, then you replace the streak of minuses with a single `-`. For example `--1 = 1` and `---1 = -1`. In the `sign == -1` condition, if the previous position saved in `st` is an operand, a closing paranthesis (any kind) or a factorial sign, then its a binary minus, else it must be a unary minus. Same with unary plus.

Once you tokenise the operator as unary it is easy to evaluate, but you need to decide based on the type of operator. If it is binary, pop twice and apply the binary operator, if it is unary, pop once and apply the operator.